# 'Parameter declaration <x> should be a vector' error when running as leiningen project

Tags: clojure

I'm learning Clojure, using "Clojure for the Brave and True". At the end of [Chapter 3: A Clojure Crash Course](http://www.braveclojure.com/do-things/), there's an example where we hit a randomly selected body part of a hobbit.

The code runs fine for me when I run it in a REPL. To check that I'd understood how to create and run clojure projects, I created a project by running `lein new app clojure-crash-course` and then edited the resulting src/clojure_crash_course/core.clj file, like so:

```
(ns clojure-crash-course.core
  (:gen-class))

(defn -main
  (hit asym-hobbit-body-parts))

(def asym-hobbit-body-parts [{:name "head" :size 3}
                             {:name "left-eye" :size 1}
                             {:name "left-ear" :size 1}
                             {:name "mouth" :size 1}
                             {:name "nose" :size 1}
                             {:name "neck" :size 1}
                             {:name "left-shouler" :size 3}
                             {:name "left-upper-arm" :size 3}
                             {:name "chest" :size 10}
                             {:name "back" :size 10}
                             {:name "left-foream" :size 3}
                             {:name "abdomen" :size 6}
                             {:name "left-kidney" :size 1}
                             {:name "left-hand" :size 2}
                             {:name "left-knee" :size 2}
                             {:name "left-thigh" :size 4}
                             {:name "left-lower-leg" :size 3}
                             {:name "left-achilles" :size 1}
                             {:name "left-foot" :size 2}])

(defn matching-part
  [part]
  {:name (clojure.string/replace (:name part) #"^left-" "right-")
   :size (:size part)})  

(defn symmetrize-body-parts
  [asym-body-parts]
  (reduce (fn [final-body-parts part]
              (into final-body-parts (set [part (matching-part part)])))
          []
          asym-body-parts))

(defn hit
  [asym-body-parts]
  (let [sym-body-parts (symmetrize-body-parts asym-body-parts)
        body-part-size-sum (reduce + (map :size sym-body-parts))
        target (rand body-part-size-sum)]
    (loop [[part & remaining] sym-body-parts
           accumulated-size (:size part)]
      (if (> accumulated-size target)
          part
          (recur remaining (+ accumulated-size (:size (first remaining))))))))
```

When I run this with `lein run`, I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter declaration hit should be a vector, compiling:(clojure_crash_course/core.clj:2:16)

I've copy/pasted `asym-hobbit-body-parts`, `asym-hobbit-body-parts`, `asym-hobbit-body-parts` and `hit` from my source file into the REPL and can then run `(hit asym-hobbit-body-parts)` fine, so I'm confident it's not a typo or similar in those functions/definitions.

I'm assuming the error is in:

```
(defn -main
  (hit asym-hobbit-body-parts))
```

I've tried googling the error message, but couldn't find anything that explained where I'd gone wrong.

What am I missing about how to use the `-main` function? / How Clojure projects work?

Comment: To avoid distracting folk, it is conventional to accept your own answer or delete the question.

Comment: @Thumbnail Thanks for the comment (I'm still quite new to SO). It seems that I have to wait 2 days before I can accept the answer. I guess I could delete it, but I figured that leaving it here might help the next person with the same problem (given that I didn't have much luck when I googled that error message).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I spotted the error whilst proof-reading my question.

I'd missed out the parameters from the `-main` function, it should be:

```
(defn -main
  []
  (hit asym-hobbit-body-parts))
```

Fixing that up then exposes the second error, namely that the definition of the main function needs to go at the end of the file rather than at the start. Otherwise you get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.long.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: hit in this context, compiling:(clojure_crash_course/core.clj:6:3)

since `hit` (and the other functions it subsequently uses) will not be in scope when `-main` is called.